# Creating a openstreetmap renderer in android

Tags: openstreetmap, mobile, android

I am trying to learn how the openstreetmap is rendered in android. There are already some tools out there that are rendering the maps. Specially I am focusing on offline maps renderer. There is one called osmand.

So, I wanted some suggestions should I go and study how osmand renders the map or do from scratch. I know osmand has done lot more than just rendering. It compresses the maps in obf format. So, I need to study its osmand binary format as well.

So where should I start? I mean should I go for osmand or something else. Osmand have specific implementation.

Comment: you need to download OsmandMapCreator  http://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToArticles#How_To_Inspect_binary_file

Answer (score 1):

First you must have the osm data for giving input to osmand map creator. You can download the osm data from
 http://download.geofabrik.de/
Geofabrik gives the latest updated osm data. Then download osmand map creator and open the jar file. There is an option to convert osm file to obf. After creating obf file open it in the osmand mobile device.